# PHP exhausting memory size using SoapClient

Tags: php, out-of-memory

Today my PHP application started to fail using it's email parser technology from https://github.com/rileydutton/Exchange-Web-Services-for-PHP which has worked for years.

Prior to this, the EC2 drive filled up and the site went down. I resolved the free space issue and the site came back except for the parser. I then updated the system as usual via yum and restarted services. I then rebooted the whole server.

The logs state that:

Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Allowed memory size of 314572800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1052319233 bytes) in /var/www/html/core/php/owaews/lib/NTLMSoapClient.php:10

That is the initial construct code connecting to the WSDL.

The requested memory amount changes, but this code hasn't changed in years so I'm surprised it is acting up.

PHP is set to allow 300MB of memory_usage.

I'm wondering how I can resolve this issue and its root cause.

Currently running Amazon Linux 2017.09 4.9.85-37 with Apache 2.4.27 and PHP 7.1.13 using FPM/FastCGI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently loading the WSDL remotely was causing the memory issues. Initial thoughts are changes on the OWA side returning some odd data that the site was choking on.

Thankfully, the parser code allows you to load the WSDL locally, and the problem does not occur when loaded locally.